# What is the C++11 way of reading binary files (16-bits at a time)?

Tags: c++11, fstream, binary-data

I want to read a binary file in 16 bit words. Right now, I'm using an `std::ifstream` to read into a 2 character array `c`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
  std::ifstream file("./tetris.rom", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
  char c[2];
  while (file.read(c, 2)) {
    uint16_t word = (static_cast<uint8_t>(c[0]) << 8) | static_cast<uint8_t>(c[1]);
    std::cout << "word\t" << std::hex << word << std::endl;
  }
}
```

This works for me, but is there a better (either safer or faster) way of doing this in C++11?

Comment: It depends on the intended usage. Are you going to process the file 2-byte at a time, or do you need to read it in full first?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin ideally 2-bytes at a time

Comment: "Faster" and "2 bytes at a time" don't go well together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no new APIs of reading files in C++11.

If the file fits into your RAM, the most optimal way is to map it into memory and access it as a byte array. However, the C++ standard library does not provide an API for that. You can do that with Boost though, see [Boost.Interprocess Memory Mapped Files](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file).

The usual advice stands though: start with your simple and correctly working code, benchmark and see if file reading is the bottleneck.